# Firefox: How to turn off "beep on error"

Tags: firefox, system-sounds

Using openSuse 13.1 with KDE and FF 25.0

In my bashrc -- both for root and user -- I use

```
xset b off
```

to disable the "beep on error" for all programs. FF seems to be the only one to ignore this, which is quite a nuisance as I do work frequently in a library where silence is imperiative. Using earplugs every time i search a website (strg-F) and the word is not found the "beep on error" -- always on full blast -- almost blows my brains out.

Is there an (advanced) FF setting I have overlooked?

Answer (score 32):

Open in Firefox:
`about:config`

Search for:

```
accessibility.typeaheadfind.enablesound
```

and set the value to: false

Then restart Firefox.

Comment: you may need not restart firefox

Comment: No restart is needed in 2019, and thanks for solving these annoying beeps. Works on MacOS too.

Comment: Playing a sound by default when the search string doesn't exist is a complete nonsense, thanks for the solution. I wonder where do Mozilla developers work, likely not in an open space.

Comment: @sorin using win 10 in 2023. Restart is not needed. I also set `accessibility.typeaheadfind.soundURL` to blank.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent any beep, `sudo rmmod pcspkr` will remove the kernel module that makes beep.

Writing `blacklist pcspkr` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` will prevent the module for being loaded again.

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go. OP wants to disble beep in FF and not for entire system

Answer (score 0):

Use the `alsamixer` command. Hit F6, select your sound card. Use right arrow to navigate to the **Beep** bar. Either hold the down arrow until it is at zero or just hit the number 0.

Also, maybe you want **Auto-Mute** enabled. It's hard to tell. This will make it so you can have your laptop speakers at 0 and then plug in earbuds/headphones and they will have sound at a different setting. The disable of beep  will still carryover, however.

Comment: Ecept the normal sound card, there is Console Audio Control, and I can't change the volume of it, even with sudo.